# Joomla: Is it possible to type text in two columns?

Tags: css, layout, joomla

I'm using the Beez2 theme. I need to know if I can simply enter text in the editor and make it show in 2 columns without using any CSS/html.

I'm referring to Joomla 1.6

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No You Can't! Not without any CSS/HTML.

Comment: I thought as much; I regret having chosen a CMS. It's the same time in that we ultimately use to complete a site. The only good thing is that once done, changes can be made 'quite' easily. But I don't see it as a trade-off. Thanks!

Comment: @Ahmd Alfy, It's not that the answer is easy, rather, it's extremely useful. I come from a 25 year development background. I thought of trying out a CMS since there's so much talk about them being able to edit like on a word processor. But I realise that it's only talk. This answer sheds light on the fact that we still have to do the ground work although you literally enter text in a box. So I'm now convinced that a CMS is NOT the way to go for most of my projects.

Comment: If I may comment. A CMS is simply a tool to help you store and organize your content in a "fast" and useful manner. If you require visual "trickery" for the way you display your content, in essence that is beside the CMS's objective and you must use HTML and CSS as that is the only way to add structure and styling to the content. Don't forget that with the "advent" of CSS3 multi-column text is right around the corner: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css3multicolumn/